# c# linkedlist how to get the the element that is before the last element

Tags: c#, linked-list

i try to implement a redo undo in my windows form application.

i build a linkedlist , every entery of the list is a class that save the state of all the elemnts in the form.

every click on the save button , insert to this list the last state of the form elements.

when the user click on undo button i want to get the entery of the list (one before the last)
and load it.

i dont know what is the simple way to get this one before elemnts from the linked list ?

my code like look like:

```
 public class SaveState {

          public int comboBox1;
          public int comboBox2;
          ..........
          public SaveState() {
           .......
          }
    }
    LinkedList<SaveState> RedoUndo = new LinkedList<SaveState>();

    # in save function
    var this_state = new SaveState();           
    this_state = getAllState();
    RedoUndo.AddLast(this_state);

    # when click undo
    var cur_state = new SaveState();
    # this lines dont work !!!!!!!!!
    int get = RedoUndo.Count - 1;        
    cur_state = RedoUndo.Find(get);
    setAllState(cur_state);
```

Comment: Why not use a stack instead of a linked list?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get the last node via [`LinkedList<T>.Last`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132188.aspx)

```
// list is LinkedList<T> for some T
var last = list.Last;
```

and the penultimate node via [`LinkedListNode<T>.Previous`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/de80z2x6.aspx)

```
var penultimate = last.Previous; // or list.Last.Previous;
```

Note that this is a [`LinkedListNode<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ahf4c754.aspx) and you need to use the [`LinkedListNode<T>.Value`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ahf4c754.aspx) property get the underlying instance of `T`.

Of course, you should take care to check that `list` is not null, and `list.Last` is not null (in the case of an empty list), and that `list.Last.Previous` is not null (in the case of a single-element list).

Answer (score 1):

@Haim, you may want to check out Krill Osenkov's [Undo Framework](http://undo.codeplex.com/). It makes undo/redo very easy.