# Get value from last element LinkedList C#

Tags: c#, linked-list

I have a LinkedList like this:

```
LinkedList<KeyValuePair<decimal, decimal>> qCompras = new LinkedList<KeyValuePair<decimal,   decimal>>();
```

I want to obtain the value from the last object in the LinkedList, but I want to know the first of the two decimal. 
How can I do this?

Thanks in advance!

Regards

Comment: qCompras.Last.Key ???

Comment: Not exactly a duplicate, but this should help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4701723/c-sharp-linkedlist-how-to-get-the-the-element-that-is-before-the-last-element

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var result = qCompras.Last.Value.Key;
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the [LinkedList.Last Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132188.aspx) property of the LinkedList?

For example:

```
var lastItem = qCompras.Last;
```

In there, you have the `Key` and `Value` properties.

Note that this is a `LinkedListNode<T>` and you need to use the `LinkedListNode<T>.Value` property get the underlying instance of `T`.